# Missing required parameter To in the post body

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm not sure if the header or the body are configured incorrectly.
Any thoughts on whether to change the headers or maybe the body is misconfigured?

```
const axios = require('axios');
  const url = '/my_url';
  const auth = {
    username: username,
    password: password
  };

  const requestbody = {
    To: 'phone',
    From: 'phone 2'
  };

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
  const config = {
    auth: auth,
    headers: headers
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, {data: requestbody}, config);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Error like:
`message: 'Missing required parameter To in the post body'`

Comment: In https://github.com/axios/axios readme docs, it passing `requestbody` directly. try `axios.post(url, requestbody, config);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to stringify parameters and then pass directly

```
const querystring = require('query-string');

  const query = querystring.stringify({
  To: 'phone',
    From: 'phone 2'
  });
  let options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': AUTH_HEADER,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };
    let axios_res = await post(url, query , options);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent hours trying to work this out today and this has solved it <3